# Unreal Development Kit Portals/Teleporters

Tags: portal, unreal-development-kit

I'm trying to use UTTeleporterCustomMeshes in UDK in a way that is similar to the behavior in the game Portal (the actual portal itself, not the portal gun).

That is:

1. You can shoot through them as well as walk through them (**DONE**)
2. It appears as if you can see through the portal as if it were a window (**DONE**)
3. You can stand half way through a portal and be at both sides simultaneously
4. Shadows and light will also carry through the teleporter

My problem is that I can't seem to find any ***detailed*** documentation for UTTeleporters.

Do the teleporters have some built in functionality for this kind of stuff or do I need to implement it all myself?
Ie, create a custom camera to capture the scene to be rendered onto my teleporter and create my own custom teleporter script?

I'm just after SOME sort of direction or ideas ast to how I could achieve this.

Cheers

**EDIT**:
I've since managed to get steps 1 and 2 working (UTPortal did the trick), though 3 and 4 still remain a challenge.

My first mistake was trying to use UTTeleporterCustomMeshes.
No matter where I went through, it would always spit me out at the middle of the target teleporter. Plus I'd have to do something like @Sebastian said with the TextureRenderTarget.

I still have a long way to go before it starts to look seamless!!

Then, onto stage 2!

Comment: I remember that the map editor documentation for the very first Unreal game recommended that you connect corridors to rooms by "invisible" portals, for performance reasons. I wish I could get a hold on current documentation as well. But I'm fairly sure that yes, all that functionality is already built in.

Answer (score 0):

Unreal does as far as I know does not support that type of behavior.
You can however build it yourself.

I would look at the TextureRenderTarget classes for rendering the material on the portal.
Standing in the portal with one foot on each "side" will be... very tricky to do but shooting and walking through them should be simple enough by extending the touch event in actor.